# How do I check which version of PeopleSoft I am using?

Tags: peoplesoft

I want to find out which version of [Oracle PeopleSoft](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/peoplesoft-enterprise/overview/index.html) we use at my office. (For reference, PeopleSoft is a corporate webapp for managing employee data).

How can I check which version of PeopleSoft I am using?

Comment: @pnuts Ctrl-J worked perfectly. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66831/discussion-between-steven-vascellaro-and-pnuts).